# Display label per state using UsMap

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display one state using [UsMap](http://newsignature.github.io/us-map).

My idea is to have something similary with these picture.

[image: CO State in US]

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```
$('#map').usmap({
    stateStyles: {
        fill: "#ccc"
    },
    stateSpecificStyles: {
        'CO': {
             fill: 'orange'
        },
    },
    showLabels: false;
 });
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dennypc/u8552/)

Although that plugin doesn't have a single state label option.